# React code shows errors in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 10.0.4 for React getting started manual.

I encountered errors of `expression expected` in the end of the code lines.

Any idea of which definitions in the WebStorm may help ?

Comment: check if you've closed all your html tags.  Maybe share your code?

Comment: Please also try some newer WebStorm version -- current 2016.3 is like v14 now

Comment: There were a lot of react errors and warnings until a couple of months ago, so with the version of years ago, there are no settings that will really help.

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm 10 doesn't understand JSX syntax, and there are no settings that would help to get it parsed properly. You have to update to the most recent version that provides enhanced support for React; see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/tag/react/